# websocketpp asio listen error

Tags: c++, boost-asio, websocket++

I have a multi-threaded websocketpp server. With no clients connected when I quit the program and relaunch, it works with no issues.

However when a client is connected and I quit/relaunch, the program throws this error

```
[2017-08-06 15:36:05] [info] asio listen error: system:98 ()
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'websocketpp::exception'
   what():  Underlying Transport Error
Aborted
```

I believe I have a proper disconnect sequence going and I have the following message (my own debug info) when I initiate the quit sequence

```
[2017-08-06 15:35:55] [control] Control frame received with opcode 8
on_close
[2017-08-06 15:35:55] [disconnect] Disconnect close local:[1000] remote:[1000]
Quitting :3
Waiting for thread
```

What does the asio error mean? I am hoping someone has seen this before so that I can begin troubleshooting. Thanks!

EDIT:
I am adapting the stock broadcast_server example where

```
typedef std::map<connection_hdl, connection_data, std::owner_less<connection_hdl> > con_list;
con_list m_connections;
```

Code to close connections.

```
lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_connection_lock);
std::cout << "Closing Server" << std::endl;
con_list::iterator it;
for (it = m_connections.begin(); it != m_connections.end(); ++it)
{
    m_server.close(it->first, websocketpp::close::status::normal, "", ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        std::cout << "> Error initiating client close: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    m_connections.erase(it->first);
}
```

Also in destructor for broadcast_server class I have a `m_server.stop()`

Comment: Do you properly close the connection ? Where is the code ?

Comment: @Blacktempel: Yeah I have used code from the examples on github to close connections. I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever there's a `websocketpp::exception`, I first check anywhere I'm explicitly using the endpoint, in your case `m_server`.

For instance, it could be somewhere where you are calling `m_server.send(...)`. Since you're multithreading, it's very possible that one of the threads may be trying to utilize a `connection_hdl` while it has already been closed by a different thread.

In that case, it's usually a `websocketpp::exception invalid state`. <s>I'm not sure for the `Underlying Transport Error`.</s>

You can use breakpoints to spot the culprit (or put a bunch of `cout` sequences in different methods, and see which sequence is broken before the exception is thrown), or use a try/catch:

```
try {
    m_server.send(hdl, ...);
    // or
    m_server.close(hdl, ...);
    // or really anything you're trying to do using `m_server`.
} catch (const websocketpp::exception &e) {//by safety, I just go with `const std::exception` so that it grabs any potential exceptions out there.
    std::cout << "Exception in method foo() because: " << e.what() /* log the cause of the exception */ << std::endl;
}
```

Otherwise, I have noticed that it will sometimes throw an exception when you're trying to close a `connection_hdl`, even if no other thread is seemingly accessing it. But if you put it in a try/catch, although it still throws the exception, since it doesn't terminate the program, it eventually closes the handler.

Also, maybe try `m_server.pause_reading(it->first)` before calling `close()` to freeze activity from that handler.

---

After second look, I think the exception you're getting is thrown where you listen with `m_server.listen(...)`. Try surrounding it with a try/catch and putting a custom logging message.